# Number of databases are not shown in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Mongo client (mongo.exe) successfully connected mongodb server(mongod.exe). When i created data base, it created and showed. But when i run this command "show dbs;", it did not show anything.
Check the following command line.

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongod.exe
2015-12-18T18:22:46.461+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2015-12-18T18:23:01.357+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:49260 #1 (1 connection now open)
```

client side(mongo.exe)

```
C:\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe
2015-12-18T18:23:01.325+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Hotfix KB2731284 or later update is installed, no need to zero-out data files
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: test
> show dbs;//initially no database
local  0.000GB
> use helloworld//create new database
switched to db helloworld
> db  //current database
helloworld
> show dbs; //no.of databases in mongodb
local  0.000GB
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create at least one document in database, after you database will show up in list.

[Create Database](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_create_database.htm)

Comment: thank brother it is working. Now it showed all databases.

Answer (score 1):

I can see your mongodb version as 3.2. Earlier versions of MongoDB(till 3.0) were having database named **test**. From 3.2 versions, I think MongoDB team dropped test database.

Even if database is not present in MongoDB, it will not error when you issue `use <db>` command(as it supports flexible schema). So, create a database as said by Vladislav Kievski.

Comment: if database not present, to show some warning or alert message, then we can identify easily.

Comment: Didn't understand your question completely. Could you please clarify? If database is not present and if you try to access it, it will not throw any error as it supports dynamic, flexible schema. You can try on your own. Without creating a database, try creating a collection by inserting a random document. Post insertion, you should see database and collection are created for you without being created explicitly.

Comment: If database is not present and if we try to access it, it show some warning or alert message(like this present no database in server, add new data), then we can identify easily. this my intention brother.

Comment: If my answer has added any value to your question or cleared your doubt, please upvote! Thanks